# Index accuracy based on sample size out of population size

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size, sample, small-sample

Suppose I have people who work at different companies and I am interested in seeing their view on some topic.

In order to do this, I decide to conduct interviews on people from each of the different companies and from these interviews I come up with an index that ranges from -100 to 100 that measures each person’s view on the topic (-100 being negative, 100 being positive).

After getting an index for each person, I decide to average indexes of people who work at the same company to get a “company index”.

Suppose the distribution of people who work at each of the companies is the following:

```
Company     # of People in Company
A           1
B           6
C           10
D           8
E           15
F           4
```

In the end, I want to end up with something like:

```
Company     # of People in Company  Index for Company
A           1                   40.3    
B           6                   0.5
C           10                  -30
…           …                   …
```

My question is: how many people should I interview from each company so that the index calculated for the company is accurate/valid? I presume this would be based on the company size, as well as the desired confidence band size for the index.

What would be an example for each of these if I wanted a confidence band of say +-20?

What would be the confidence level if, for example, only 1 person was interviewed from company B (out of 6)? Or 2 people with variance of X?

Comment: Basically you would need to perform power analysis for each company separately. Do you have any data already?

Comment: @user2974951 I do - I have a couple of indexes for different people within each company. For example, for company B I have indexes for two people: 0 and 1, and for company C I have indexes from 3 (0, -50, -40), and company F I have only one person with index of 23. How would I go about conducting the power analysis for each of these?

Comment: Assuming that we treat this index as a numeric variable and therefore want to use a t-test, you woul need a power analysis for a t-test, in base R with `power.t.test`, where you input the known data from your preliminary sample (mean, SD, ...) and you get out n (sample size required) for the desired accuracy.

Comment: @user2974951 Even if I treat it is numeric, would a t-test be appropriate in this case? I don't want to test whether the index is different from 0, but simply get a confidence band around the index and see how "reliable" that estimate is based on population size? This would be like trying to estimate a population mean from sample

Comment: You can ignore the test for equality with 0 if you like, or alternatively set an arbitraty number instead of 0, either way you will get the mean and CI for the mean out of a t-test. If the p-value is not important / relevant you can just ignore it.

Comment: @user2974951 Thanks - this is helpful when calculating the confidence interval. But when using `power t-test` to calculate desired sample size, it requires me to provide a `delta`, i.e. true difference in means. The sample size that it outputs depends on the true difference in means, so cannot be calculated when there is no test against true mean. (0 gives a very large sample size, and 20 gives a very small for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to solve this from a different, simpler perspective. Basically, we want to estimate the sample size needed to get a certain Standard Error (which will be used to construct the Confidence Interval). For this I will make some assumptions, which may be more or less correct, but we have to start somewhere.

I will assume the data come from a normal distribution. I don't have any data so I will just simulate some at random. So suppose I have 6 data points with some values

```
> set.seed(2019)
> dat=rnorm(6,runif(1,-100,100),runif(1,0,50))
> mean(dat); sd(dat)
[1] 38.82794
[1] 37.29289
> dat
[1] 35.633223 -4.479012 86.629680  8.804734 80.292927 26.086079
```

For the normal distribution it stands that the standard error is

$$SE=\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$

So inverting this formula we can estimate n by

$$n=\Big(\dfrac{\sigma}{SE}\Big)^2$$

We estimate $\sigma$ from the data, in this case it's $37.29289$, the standard error we want it to be 10. Why? Because in your specifications you said you wanted to have a CI of $\pm20$, which I am going to assume you meant a 95 % CI. So if we set $SE=10$ we will get the 95 % CI (roughly 2 standard deviations). Finally we plug in the numbers and get

```
> (sd(dat)/10)^2
[1] 13.9076
```

So you need 14 observations for the desired CI.